# split single line to a multiple lines based on a pattern in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have the following data in single line.

**Input**

```
pid:1230 received at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:230,message ID:1200,Field1:anil,Field3:kumar,Field4:nitin,Field5:Rajat,Field6:Yogesh,Field7:Kishore,Field8:satya,pid:1230 sent message at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:232,message ID:1200,name1:anil,name3:kumar,name4:nitin,name5:Rajat,name6:Yogesh,name7:Kishore,name8:satya,pid:1230 Received message at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:232,message ID:1200,nkd1:anil,nkd3:kumar,nkd4:nitin,nkd5:Rajat,nkd6:Yogesh,nkd7:Kishore,nkd8:satya,pid:1230 sent at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:232,message ID:1200,Field1:anil,Field3:kumar,Field4:nitin,Field5:Rajat,Field6:Yogesh,Field7:Kishore,Field8:satya,pid:1230 received at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:230,message ID:1200,Field1:anil,Field3:kumar,Field4:nitin,Field5:Rajat,Field6:Yogesh,Field7:Kishore,Field8:satya,pid:1230 sent message at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:232,message ID:1200,name1:anil,name3:kumar,name4:nitin,name5:Rajat,name6:Yogesh,name7:Kishore,name8:satya,pid:1230 Received message at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:232,message ID:1200,nkd1:anil,nkd3:kumar,nkd4:nitin,nkd5:Rajat,nkd6:Yogesh,nkd7:Kishore,nkd8:satya,pid:1230 sent at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:232,message ID:1200,Field1:anil,Field3:kumar,Field4:nitin,Field5:Rajat,Field6:Yogesh,Field7:Kishore,Field8:satya
```

I want to break the single line to multiple lines. If the field contains "received at" then i want to split to a newline. Above single line can be split to 2 lines.

**Expected output:**

```
pid:1230 received at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:230,message ID:1200,Field1:anil,Field3:kumar,Field4:nitin,Field5:Rajat,Field6:Yogesh,Field7:Kishore,Field8:satya,pid:1230 sent message at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:232,message ID:1200,name1:anil,name3:kumar,name4:nitin,name5:Rajat,name6:Yogesh,name7:Kishore,name8:satya,pid:1230 Received message at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:232,message ID:1200,nkd1:anil,nkd3:kumar,nkd4:nitin,nkd5:Rajat,nkd6:Yogesh,nkd7:Kishore,nkd8:satya,pid:1230 sent at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:232,message ID:1200,Field1:anil,Field3:kumar,Field4:nitin,Field5:Rajat,Field6:Yogesh,Field7:Kishore,Field8:satya
pid:1230 received at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:230,message ID:1200,Field1:anil,Field3:kumar,Field4:nitin,Field5:Rajat,Field6:Yogesh,Field7:Kishore,Field8:satya,pid:1230 sent message at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:232,message ID:1200,name1:anil,name3:kumar,name4:nitin,name5:Rajat,name6:Yogesh,name7:Kishore,name8:satya,pid:1230 Received message at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:232,message ID:1200,nkd1:anil,nkd3:kumar,nkd4:nitin,nkd5:Rajat,nkd6:Yogesh,nkd7:Kishore,nkd8:satya,pid:1230 sent at date 12/1/15 17:00:00:232,message ID:1200,Field1:anil,Field3:kumar,Field4:nitin,Field5:Rajat,Field6:Yogesh,Field7:Kishore,Field8:satya
```

Can you please help me. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like what you're really trying to do is insert a newline before every occurrence of `pid:`.

Comment: not every occurrence of pid., i want to insert newline when pid is having "received at" string.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a minimal example, containing a representative sample of your input data. Remove some of the fields to make each line short and show us some examples of places where a newline should *not* be inserted (if there are any), as well as where they should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed 's/,\(pid:[0-9]* received at\)/\n\1/g' yourfile
```

Comment: Thanks Sat. Its working.